# git - commit single repository in empty directory without having downloaded repo

Tags: git

Is it possible to *not* have to download the entire repo before making a commit, i.e., to commit just a single local file or local folder by itself (without already having the existing stuff in the repo in the local directory)?

Specifically:

I have in a *local* directory, **only** the following to commit (with all files inside the directory):

`\Local\SingleFolder`

The *local* directory **only** contains that single folder.

The *remote* directory, contains `lots of stuff`:

```
Folder1
Folder2
file1.cpp
anotherfile.cpp
...
(etc)
```

I don't want to download all that stuff locally.

Can I commit just my single `\Local\SingleFolder` without having to download `lots of stuff`?

--

Reason: computer with these files is on low disk space (blame apple tiny Flash drives), and I only need to commit one folder to an existing large repo. I'm trying to avoid having to USB this...

Comment: While I don't think this is possible, you could get similar results by downloading a single file, modifying it, using diff to get a patch file, and sending that to somebody who could then apply the patch.

Comment: is the repo on a service like github or bitbucket?, you could just fork the `origin` to your account ,  make the changes the single file -through the web interface- and submit a pull request

Comment: If your git-fu is strong try `git hash-object`, `git mktree` and `git commit-tree` .  USB is sounding pretty compelling to me though.

Comment: yes, it's a private repo on github... but, the single file is binary though. github seems to only allow ascii/text files for add single file

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I see you can do it unless you have the repository locally somewhere (on some other machine also).

What you can do:
1. Create a new folder and make it a git repo (`git init`)
2. Add `\Local\SingleFolder` and commit it.
3. Create a patch of that commit (`git format-patch -1`)
4. Mail the patch to someone who has the repository downloaded(cloned)
5. Ask them to do `git am --ignore-whitespace <patch-file>` to whichever branch you require
6. Push it!

Et voila!

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Couldn't it be possible to push directly a branch containing only `\Local\SingleFolder` and then merge on server or another local repo ?

Comment: For the branch to be there you need the repo. Ina dosent have the repo nor the place to have the repo. If what you say was possible then there was no problem at all!